# Trying to add background color to header only

Tags: css, reactjs

Im trying to add a color to my header only, but instead it'll add that color to the entire table.

`

```
 <div className="container" style={buttonStyle}>
                <text id={i} onClick={this.ChangeVisibility} style={{cursor:"pointer"}}>{} {this.showImage(i)}</text>
                <table style = {tableStyle} bgcolor ='#CCE4FF'  id={i + "table"} className="table table-borderless">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Column Headers</th>
                            <th>Incedo Pay Attribute</th>
                            <th>Data Type</th>
                            <th>Min Length</th>
                            <th>Max Length</th>
                            <th>Is Mandatory ?</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody className="table-group-divider">
                        {tmp}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>
```

`

Comment: You appear to be applying the color to the `table` tag which is the entire table. `thead` signifies the table header but you will have more luck if you style either the `tr` (table row) or `th` (header cell) within the `thead`.

Answer (score 0):

You Can set particular th tag

or

you can change color via css `th{ background:cyan; }`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure here because your code is incomplete.
You don't show where `tableStyle` and other variables are defined. However, it's possible to see that when you apply style to `table` tag it applies for the whole table.

To overcome this you could either use `tableStyle` in the `thead` as it is shown below:

```
<div className="container" style={buttonStyle}>
  <text id={i} onClick={this.ChangeVisibility} style={{cursor:"pointer"}}>
    {} {this.showImage(i)}
  </text>
  <table bgcolor ='#CCE4FF'  id={i + "table"} className="table table-borderless">
    <thead style={tableStyle}>
      <tr>
        <th>Column Headers</th>
        <th>Incedo Pay Attribute</th>
        <th>Data Type</th>
        <th>Min Length</th>
        <th>Max Length</th>
        <th>Is Mandatory ?</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody className="table-group-divider">
      {tmp}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Or if you want two different styles then you can define a header specific style e.g. `tableHeadStyle` and apply it to `thead`:

```
<div className="container" style={buttonStyle}>
  <text id={i} onClick={this.ChangeVisibility} style={{cursor:"pointer"}}>{} {this.showImage(i)}
  </text>
  <table style={tableStyle} bgcolor ='#CCE4FF'  id={i + "table"} className="table table-borderless">
    <thead >
    ...
```